# Excel TEXT function: user-dependent behavior of date formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, formatting, language, date

We're on a standardized Citrix / Windows 2008R2 environment with Regional Settings set to Dutch for all users, and English-language Excel 2010 for all users. Nevertheless, the behavior of the TEXT function when formatting dates is user-dependent.

Date formatting in English and Dutch differs only in the year (day and month are "d" and "m" in both languages). As expected, with our Dutch regional settings, "jjjj" is the formatting code to display the year. For most users, this works fine: =TEXT(TODAY(); "dd/mm/jjjj") displays "03/05/2017".

However, when some users open the worksheet containing this text function, they get "03/05/jjjj", as if their Regional Settings are set to English. But when I check their Regional Settings, they're set to Dutch, as expected. Nor can I discover any other language- or locale-related settings that are different for these users.

Now I thought Regional Settings was the only determining factor in the behavior of the formatting string in the TEXT function. But apparently, there are more, and those are user-dependent, i.e. stored in HKCU. Also, since my users seem to be able to change them unwittingly, these additional settings are accessible through the UI.

Where else than in Regional Settings is the behavior of date formatting in the TEXT function determined?

Comment: besides regional settings also Office language settings may influence language of functions, did you compared them too?

Comment: Yes, Maté, good point. I'm checking those with my user next week. I think we have those locked down through GPO though.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that spring to mind are:

1) You could simply enter the date and format that specific cell/range to "short date" format instead.

2) If you're not averse to using a bit of VBA you could run a sub from the `Workbook_Open()` event that formats the cell. VBA uses English regardless, so:

```
Sheets("Foo").Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

would work regardless of the client's regional settings.

Comment: Thanks, Macro Man. I've actually created a different workaround: `=TEXT(TODAY();"dd-mm-")&YEAR(TODAY())`. However, I'm looking for an explanation and a fix for the root cause. This should not happen at all in our standardized environment.

Comment: Unfortunately the format string is also language dependent.